# Several crashes after upgrading to 14.10 from 14.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, nautilus, crash, 14.10

I upgraded my system today from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. There were issues because I was using Gnome 3.12 from "ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging". I was able to fix the issues (unmet dependencies, broken packages). However, there are now several applications that crash regularly. My assumption is that this is because of the issues I had with Gnome after upgrading. Crashes only happen if specific operations are performed.

Applications that now regularly crash:

- nautilus (e.g. when I right click on a file and choose "Open With ->
  Other Application" or when I switch window from nautilus to something
  else with Alt+Tab)
- gnome-tweak-tool (e.g. when I try to change Window theme or to remove an extension)
- background (when I click on the "Background" or "Lock Screen" image)

What I already tried (always with the same result as before):

- Installed Gnome 3.14 using [these instructions](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/09/time-to-install-gnome-3-14-on-ubuntu-14-10/)
- Reinstalled applications

I appreciate any tips on what else I could try out.

Comment: I just figured out that when you launch an app (such as nautilus) through a terminal. When it crashes it says *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*
Don't know if it can help

Comment: @Thyseeker I also noticed that, it always gave a segfault in g_closure_invoke().

Answer (score 2):

So I resolved the issue now, but I did not found a simple solution. I basically did a fresh install of gnome:

1. Used synaptic to remove anything related to gnome, ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-session (mark for complete removal)
2. Ran "sudo apt-get -f install" to resolve unmet dependencies
3. Ran "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell" to reinstall gnome

This did the trick for me.

Comment: With this way, did you manage to have a working GNOME 3.14 on Ubuntu 14.10? This seems to be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1385598) and it'd be nice if we can pinpoint what package actually causes this. Do you think you can provide the list of the packages you removed?

Comment: No I did not try to install GNOME 3.14. I am happy with GNOME 3.12 now. How can I get a list from all the removed packages?

Comment: I also did sudo apt-get install gnome in addition to this.

Comment: How do I use synaptic to remove those things?

Comment: You dont need synaptic. Just run the command sudo apt-get remove gnome* ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-session*

Answer (score -1):

just do a ppa purge everything will be F9

Run

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

it will revert your system back to official versions of all gtk things that come by defAult

i hv dOnE it mAH selF ...||

Comment: this does nothing on its own