# problem with Gnome and how to upgrade it

Tags: 14.04, gnome, upgrade, flash

I have gnome 3.10.4 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 from software center.

problem: when I click on full screen for video on youtube, I get a notification about it and when I click on it, the full screen of that video opens as a separate window. What's wrong ? this sometimes keeps adobe flash crashed

second concern: how to upgrade gnome from 3.10 to 3.14. i didnt found any tutorial on net. and I didn't tried to do it myself,I don't wanted to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from Gnome shell 3.10 to 3.14 is highly risky. Things may break. Only if you are sure/patient, then continue. Or else its better to stick with your version

Saying that, this is the procedure (I tried on Ubuntu Gnome and it worked after fixing lots of things. )

1)First upgrade to Gnome 3.12 - http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/how-to-install-gnome-312-in-ubuntu.html

2)Then upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10

3)Now upgrade to Gnome 3.14 - http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html

If any things break you can follow - [Several crashes after upgrading to 14.10 from 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541486/several-crashes-after-upgrading-to-14-10-from-14-04) . This worked for me.

Backup your system for sure before starting this.

Comment: Upgrading to Gnome 3.12 before upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 is not necessary. It actually increases risk of having problems during the upgrade.

Comment: Its better if you upgrade to 3.12 first before upgrading to 3.14. I haven't tried installing 3.14 directly but generally its advised to do incremental upgrades

Comment: is it must to upgrade to 14.10 for gnome 3.14 ?

Comment: @ToDo since 3.14 is released, I assume 3.12 is stable now ?

Comment: Yes, 3.14 works only on 14.10. Yes 3.12 is stable. Even 3.14 is also stable. No issues found so far

Comment: @mac the link you gave above both gave same method to install gnome. which is why i cant first install 3.12 then 3.14. its one way direct 3.14